# Problem when trying to create a dynamic list by Sequence Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a list of Sequence using A1:A4 as input and result in C1 using recursive LAMBDA
[image: Example]

This is my formula so far:

```
=LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="",a,VSTACKSEQUENCE(VSTACK(a,b),SEQUENCE(OFFSET(b,1,0),1,1,1))))
```

How ever the formula in `E1 =VSTACKSEQUENCE(1,A1)` return as [image]

Anyone can help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the formula in E1 relate to your formula so far? Does your "formula so far" work?

Comment: In order to SPILL the sequence you need a LAMBDA helper. The LAMBDA itself (such as `=LET(x,LAMBDA(a,b,TOCOL(VSTACK(a,SEQUENCE(b)))),x(1,A1:A4))` would work, but will only return each first value of the sequence and not return the rest, since it uses 1 cell per time as argument and returns 1 cell per argument.

Comment: @SolarMike Hi, my formula in E1 is surely not working, but I don't know why, because I'm trying to create new one using recursive Lambda with similar basis like this `LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="",a,SumRecursive(SUM(a,b),OFFSET(b,1,0))))(1,A1)` which is working just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to stack a sequence of the number mentioned in the range row wise. So your example picture shows an extra `1` in the beginning? (see edit below).

In that case you could make use of MAKEARRAY:

Test formula:
`=LET(STACKSEQUENCE,LAMBDA(range,TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(range),MAX(range),LAMBDA(r,c,LET(p,INDEX(range,r),IF(c>p,x,c)))),2)),STACKSEQUENCE(A1:A4))`

You can create name `STACKSEQUENCE` in the name manager and use `LAMBDA(range,TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(range),MAX(range),LAMBDA(r,c,LET(p,INDEX(range,r),IF(c>p,x,c)))),2))`

[image]

You could also choose to truly stack them using REDUCE:
`LAMBDA(range,REDUCE(SEQUENCE(@range),DROP(range,1),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,SEQUENCE(y)))))`

or using less characters as suggested by Ike:
`=LAMBDA(d,DROP(REDUCE(0,d,LAMBDA(r,i,VSTACK(r,SEQUENCE(i)))),1))`

EDIT:
I see you had an extra argument as  input and that was the start value.
You could still use the formulas above to get your intended result, like:

=`VSTACK(1,STACKSEQUENCE(A1:A4))`

Comment: No need for `TAKE`: this works as well: `=LAMBDA(d,DROP(REDUCE("",d,LAMBDA(r,i,VSTACK(r,SEQUENCE(i)))),1))(A1:A4)`

Comment: Yeah, also possible. I avoided the DROP(); you avoided the TAKE(). Yours is shorter, mine doesn't return an extra line that needs removal (DROP).

Comment: @Ike I decided to reference it in the post. Also changed my `TAKE(range,1)` into `@range` which is the same, but triggers a suggestion to a (wrong) variation of the formula when not using the named LAMBDA, but when using the named LAMBDA is calculated as intended without Excel suggesting to change the formula.

Comment: @P.b @Ike all the solution listed above is working excellent in my test cases, but could you guys can explain what are the reason to avoid `Take()` or `Drop`, thank you in advance

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPCgYNVxNROq5bQT5SvtA?e=0e1Gi3
This file demonstrates the behavior of REDUCE of both cases. The main difference is in the start value of the REDUCE lambda output. Mine starts with a calculation on the 1st row in range; next it adds the calculation of the rest of the range's rows excluding the 1st. Ike's starts with a dummy start value and next it outputs all from start to end. Therefore we need to DROP the first line (the dummy start value). Ike's version is shorter in text, Mine calculates to the end result without having to remove a value. Both perform likewise.

Comment: @P.b In my understanding, both solution are using `REDUCE` to loop through the `Data`, with some tweaks, yours is in the input of `REDUCE` while @Ike's solution is at the output of `REDUCE`.  Thanks for a very comprehensive explanation!

Comment: That's exactly it.

Answer (score 3):

### VStack Consecutive Sequences

**Function "VStackSequence" (Name Manager)**

```
=LAMBDA(count,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(count),LAMBDA(rr,r,VSTACK(rr,SEQUENCE(r)))),1))
```

**Usage**

```
=LET(data,A1:A4,CHOOSEROWS(data,VStackSequence(ROWS(data))))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I think the idea was to have a sequence by the number mentioned in the range, but I guess it can be interpret thus way as well. You can do it at one using index: `=LAMBDA(range,DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,EXPAND(INDEX(range,y),y,,INDEX(range,y))))),1))(A1:A4)`

Comment: @P.b That's right, my idea is trying to create a single column, base on Sequence and VStack with given number for each Sequence. But the respond from @VBasic2008 is working perfectly with specific setup of `data` as well. Thanks you both!

Comment: @VBasics My version was off, it was just repeating the rows value the number of times of the position in the input range. This loops the way you intended `=LAMBDA(range,REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,INDEX(range,SEQUENCE(y))))))(A1:A4)`